# More Efficient: with open(file, "wb"): pass or os.remove(file)

Tags: python, performance

I have situation where I repeatedly clear a file so that another (closed-source) program in a subprocess can write at the beginning of it, multiplied by several threads.

My question is it better (less resource-intensive) to do:

```
with open(file, 'wb') as wf:
    pass
```

Or, simply:

```
os.remove(file)
```

Factor in that the subprocess is going to come along and either open or create and open the file, depending on which of these I go with.

Comment: You might want to check out the `timeit` module and give it a try - see what kind of performance you see. Honestly, I doubt it'll make much difference, and I'd go for the latter as it's (I think) clearer what you are trying to do.

Comment: Note that the first option will create a blank file, while the second will not. They are not functionally equivalent

Comment: @goncalopp I am aware. The subprocess with either open, or create and open the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like emptying the file was slightly faster, but not by much. Note I didn't use subprocess to call an external command since I assume most of the difference will be filesystem or os

```
import os
from timeit import timeit

def remove():
    os.remove('test.txt')
    external_command()

def empty():
    open('test.txt', 'wb').close()  # same as your with statement, but shorter
    external_command()

def external_command():
    ''' not actually an external command, but pretend... '''
    with open('test.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write('mooo')


print 'removal took', timeit(remove, number=1000), 'seconds'
#O: removal took 0.132004915145 seconds

print 'emptying took', timeit(empty, number=1000), 'seconds'
#O: emptying took 0.106063604726 seconds
```